# Can I start multiple profiles next to each other

Tags: visual-studio-code, profile

If i use 2 commands after each other:

```
code -n c:\code\machinelearning --profile "Default"
code -n c:\code\machinelearning --profile "MachineLearning"
```

I still end up with one VSCode instance in the profile I opened at first.

```
Windows 11 22H2 (OS Build 22621.2428)
VScode 1.83.1
f1b07bd25dfad64b0167beb15359ae573aecd2cc
x64
```

My question is: How do I run 2 profiles of VSCode paralel on one computer.

I tried it with and without the -n parameter.

Maybe I missed something: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

Comment: errr, isnt the vscode only allow one parent vscode process.

Answer (score 0):

There is an old issue on GitHub about adding support for opening the same folder twice: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2686.

The issue has been **closed** in Dec 2022 with comment "We closed this issue because we don't plan to address it in the foreseeable future".
The discussion that came before it suggests that it is not as simple as "just allowing it".

Answer (score 0):

Ja I saw that indeed, probably their answer is to use Workspaces.